# Counter sorting lost when combined with defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter

I am trying to take a list made from `(item_number, fruit)` tuples and count the number of times each type of fruit appears in the list. That's easy enough with `collections.Counter`. I'm using `most_common()` along with that.

The problem I'm running into is when trying to also show the list of item_numbers that correspond to a particular type of fruit they become out of order.

Here is my sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import Counter, defaultdict

mylist = [
            (1, 'peach'),
            (2, 'apple'),
            (3, 'orange'),
            (4, 'apple'),
            (5, 'banana'),
            (6, 'apple'),
            (7, 'orange'),
            (8, 'peach'),
            (9, 'apple'),
            (10, 'orange'),
            (11, 'plum'),
            ]

# FIRST, HANDLE JUST COUNTING THE ITEMS

normal_list = []

# append to a simple list
for item_number, fruit in mylist:
    normal_list.append(fruit)

# prints just the name of each fruit and how many times it appears
for fruit, count in Counter(normal_list).most_common(10):
    print(f'{fruit}\tCount: {count}')  

# NOW TRY TO INCLUDE THE LIST IF ITEM NUMBERS ALSO

mydefaultdict = defaultdict(list)

# append to the defaultdict
for item_number, fruit in mylist:
    mydefaultdict[fruit].append(item_number)

# prints each fruit, followed by count, and finally the list of IPs for each
for fruit, item_list in Counter(mydefaultdict).most_common(10):
    print(f'{fruit}\tCount: {len(item_list)}\tList: {item_list}')
```

I am getting the expected output for the simpler version:

```
apple   Count: 4
orange  Count: 3
peach   Count: 2
banana  Count: 1
plum    Count: 1
```

However when I try to add the item_number list to it, the results are no longer sorted which plays havoc when I use a `most_common()` value smaller than the total number of fruit varieties:

```
plum    Count: 1    List: [11]
banana  Count: 1    List: [5]
orange  Count: 3    List: [3, 7, 10]
apple   Count: 4    List: [2, 4, 6, 9]
peach   Count: 2    List: [1, 8]
```

I'm sure there is something I could be doing differently here, but I'm not quite sure what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Counter(mydefaultdict)` isn't doing what you *think* it's doing. You are feeding a `defaultdict` of *lists* to `Counter`, whose purpose is to *count occurrences*, not calculate the lengths of lists. Indeed, the *values* of your `Counter` object are just lists, not integers. `Counter` doesn't complain because it's a subclass of `dict` and like `dict` can be initialised with another dictionary.

To order by *longest list* you can use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) with a custom function:

```
from heapq import nlargest

for fruit, item_list in nlargest(10, mydefaultdict.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1])):
    print(f'{fruit}\tCount: {len(item_list)}\tList: {item_list}')

apple   Count: 4    List: [2, 4, 6, 9]
orange  Count: 3    List: [3, 7, 10]
peach   Count: 2    List: [1, 8]
banana  Count: 1    List: [5]
plum    Count: 1    List: [11]
```

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this. Your solution certainly works for this test case and that's great. The prod script actually grabs a config snippet from 300 routers, and the idea is to show me the most common snippets (because they were SUPPOSED to be templatized, but I don't have that template) so that I can use that as a baseline to compare the rest of the configs to to find anomalies that aren't part of the original template. 

Its basically part of a larger discovery effort for a network project I'm working on. I'm not even sure I'm actually going about it the right way.

Comment: Sure, the main point for the problem you've stated is to note is the "count" for each key is equal to the length of the list relating to that key. `items` extracts key-value combinations, and `len(x[1])` gets the length of the value (i.e. list). For your wider problem, I suggest you formulate a specific problem separately relating to it.

Comment: That's what's confusing to me though. I don't care about the length of the list of item numbers. I'm just printing the list of item numbers so I can see exactly which items contain the particular fruit. It's the Counter result I actually care about.

Now, I suppose one will always be exactly the same length as the other...

Comment: @ChrisJones, I'm confused. Your question seems to revolve around `the results are no longer sorted`. *What do you want to sort by?* It seems this is your desired result, but if it's not, some clarification would help.

Comment: When you use most_common() it sorts it by most common to least common. When I added the ability to see the actual items that make it the most common, they no longer appear in order of most common to least common. Or, if we once again step outside of this test case, I found that 73 of my 300 routers had the exact same config. But the script didn't tell me the name of any of those 73 routers for me to actually SSH to one. That's when I decided to add the list of routers to each line. Does that make sense? I tried to boil the code down for a test case to make it clearer.

Comment: `they no longer appear in order of most common to least common`. That's because you are defining *different* `Counter` objects before you use `most_common`. Your first is `Counter(normal_list)`, your second `Counter(mydefaultdict)`. There's no reason these should ever give the same result when you apply `most_common`.

Comment: Yes I have two of them. One to show the results without the list of item numbers and another to show with it. That's just so somebody trying my code will be able to see the difference in result.

Comment: @ChrisJones, Yep, so what I'm saying is what you're getting (the output) is precisely a consequence of your inputs. Change your inputs, your output will change, including ordering. Both wim and my solutions try to help you get round that.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to change the inputs.

Comment: @ChrisJones, Sorry to repeat myself, but that's exactly where we are helping. E.g. `nlargest(10, mydefaultdict.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))` is a different input.

Comment: Okay I guess that's where I got confused. It seemed like your suggestion was counting the length of the list rather than the actual result of the Counter

Comment: @ChrisJones, Can you give an example where they are **not** the same? Because they, by construction, are *guaranteed* to be the same.

Comment: Yes they well. It's just a different way to tackle the problem because it doesn't even use Counter anymore. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 3):

This part is difficult:

```
Counter(mydefaultdict)
```

Your object `mydefaultdict` is already populated with *lists* as the values, but `Counter` objects generally have positive integers as the values.  This is not actually an error, because `Counter` is a dict subclass, so it will accept any dict as an initializer argument. Except there's a problem: `most_common` is no longer returning sane results (in case you were curious, it's actually placing a [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) based on the lists).

Perhaps clearer would be something like this:

```
most_common_fruits = sorted(mydefaultdict, key=lambda f: len(mydefaultdict[f]), reverse=True)
for fruit in most_common_fruits:
    item_list = mydefaultdict[fruit]
    ...
```

Now the output is like this:

```
apple   Count: 4    List: [2, 4, 6, 9]
orange  Count: 3    List: [3, 7, 10]
peach   Count: 2    List: [1, 8]
banana  Count: 1    List: [5]
plum    Count: 1    List: [11]
```